# Closing Windows Forms on a Touchscreen

Tags: c#, winforms, touchscreen

Our clients have fat fingers, and so do we. We take touchscreen netbooks apart to insert them into our custom hardware, and I write a software interface that shows up on the touchscreen. The problem is that it has about a 3/4" bezel over the screen, which means hitting that little red "X" becomes a challenge, especially considering reduced capacitive ability on the edges and corners.

Is there a way to make this standard close button larger? Of course in the application I can always make really nice 80x80 buttons that are perfectly usable, but there seems to be no way to override the default frame of the form. We have tried enabling Large Fonts and all the built-in accessibility features, but nothing seems to make it large enough to hit successfully.

Simply adding a toolbar button is also not much of an option. We prefer to utilize the standard look and feel of a normal Windows application.

Alternatively, should we be looking at making some sort of "kiosk mode" where we simply go fullscreen and do nothing involving the taskbar or title bar? How difficult is this to accomplish, if so?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, since you're setting up the hardware, I presume you're able to configure preinstalled software, including Windows. Can't you just go into Display Settings and make the title bar larger, so that the close button grows accordingly?

See MS Article about distributing windows themes: http://support.microsoft.com/kb/310514

Comment: This is a perfect solution, and I wish I'd known about it before posting. I thought the appearance settings were only for color, but setting both Inactive and Active Title Bar to like 40 pixels should work just fine. Plus, this doesn't impact solutions in which we use a traditional laptop/desktop to run it. Thanks for the pointer!

Answer (score 1):

Getting a large close button is fairly easy to do.  It is hidden well since Vista, in Win7 it is Control Panel + Personalization + Window Color, Advanced appearance settings, Item = Caption buttons, change the Size.  You probably won't like this much though, you'll get a rather large caption bar, lots of waste screen real estate.

Tackling this from the other end: your request is unusual.  Most anybody that sets up a touch screen app wants to know how to *prevent* the user from closing the window.  Windows Forms makes it too easy to design a bunch of forms and switch between them.  That isn't much of a user interface on a regular desktop, especially not here.  You can design your forms as user controls as well and switch them in and out of the main window as the user navigates through the UI.  Not unlike, say, Microsoft Outlook.  You can even turn your existing form into a control.  Set its TopLevel property to False, FormBorderStyle to None, Visible to true.

Comment: Yes, I do understand the request is a bit unusual. Unlike most kiosk operations, we use a lot of legacy hardware and drivers that sometimes force the user to restart the software, thus they need a way to cleanly shut it down and restart. We've already gone from multiple forms to a single one that loads and unloads controls based on operation (as well as tabbed interfaces), but I've not thought about losing the whole border completely. I may explore this option some more, which will also gain some additional screen real estate for us. Good idea.